# How to call a java class function with javascript ajax on a localhost server

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, function, server

I got something like this:

```
package beans;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("cc")
@Stateless
public class CardBean implements ICardRemote {

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("validate/{creditCard}")
@GET
@Override
public boolean Validate(@PathParam("creditCard")String creditCard){                 
    int sum = 0;                    
     boolean alternate = false;                 
     for (int i = creditCard.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)                 
     {                         
        int n = Integer.parseInt(creditCard.substring(i, i + 1));                          
        if (alternate)                        
        {                                
             n *= 2;                                 
             if (n > 9)                              
            {                                
                n = (n % 10) + 1;                               
            }                         
         }                         
         sum += n;                        
        alternate = !alternate;                 
    }           
    return (sum % 10 == 0); //or true or false
}
}
```

There I got the function Validate

Now I got a HTML page, that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"; integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b‌​8=" crossorigin="anonymous">      </script>


</head>
<body>
<a
    href="http://localhost:8080/CreditCardWEB/rest/cc/validate/4111111111111111">Validan</a>
<br>
<a
    href="http://localhost:8080/CreditCardWEB/rest/cc/validate/4111111111111112">Nevalidan</a>
<br>

<br>
<input type="text" name="txtCC" value="4111111111111111" id="txtCC1">

<button name="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
<br>
<br>
<p id="res">Result: </p>


<script>
function myFunction() {

    //    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result:" + txtCC1.value;
        var str = txtCC1.value;

         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: './validate/'+str,                 
            success: function(data) {                               
                     document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result:" + data;          
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //Do something on ERROR here                            
            }
        });                 
}
</script>

<br>

</body>
</html>
```

So in the end, I have a text field, with a hardcoded number in it.

On button click I need to take that number and send it into my validation function.

And once the function is done, I need the result to be written below the button.....here...

```
<p id="res">Result: </p>
```

So it has to be like Result:true, or Result:false

Comment: are you suppose to use javascript? since the code can completely be done with js alone

Comment: javascript ajax jquerry is what i can use

Comment: but, i am been told to use AJAX

Comment: as per your code. it doesn't seem needed in the process. but if you really like it then so be it

Comment: hmm.. it seems that you're to get the validation from the other page. you can do so. create a page then create a request using jquery ajax/post/get . btw jquery has a built it ajax function. you can check its documentation if you want [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: i am trying the stuff below, what Mechkov posted....it's that what i need....but i cant get it done....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (**make sure you include jQuery library!**):

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result:" + txtCC1.value;
    var str = txtCC1.value;

    //Here i need a code to call my validation function 
    //like: var res=Validation (str);
    //and then do the  
    //document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result:" + res;
    //DONE


     $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './validate/'+str,   //Make sure you put the correct endpoint URL here!                
        success: function(data) { 
                    //DO SOMETHING HERE AFTER YOU GET THE RESPONSE FROM the validate function
                    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result:" + data;
                 },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //Do something on ERROR here                            
               }
    });

}
```

Comment: almost....but when i copy it to the code....where u typed the do something here after u get the response...there should the line  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result:" + data; do that what i am hoping for, that is to type Result: true....but it dose not do anything -.-

Comment: and i dont know what to do with the error part...? And in the same line, what is data? true, false? or a string of 411111....?

Comment: Error part is optional. Only if you want to get notified or do something on error. For your first question, once you get the data (note how on Success you have function(data)), so once you get the 'data' check it if it is whatever you need to set it to 'true'. You decide what the logic is going to be there

Comment: The result would be true or false, based on your Controller logic (it returns a boolean),

Comment: I do this...    function myFunction() {

  //    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result:" + txtCC1.value;
      var str = txtCC1.value;

       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: './Validate/'+str,                 
          success: function(data) {         
                   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result:" + data;
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      //Do something on ERROR here                            
          }
      });        
 }

Comment: if(data == 'true') do this else do something else

Comment: i did the if then else part....but again, nothing happens...i ll post an answer so u can take a look

Answer (score 0):

You will find answer for your question under this link: [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Read more about consuming rest service with javascript

Comment: I just cant find any way for my concrete problem....but is it possible to do it without the http request?

Comment: It is not possible, this method can be only called by HTTP GET request

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code...thx to   Mechkov

```
function myFunction() {
console.log($);
        var str = txtCC1.value;
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/CreditCardWEB/rest/cc/validate/'  +str,                 
            success: function(data) {                               
                     document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result: " + data;         
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR +' : '+ textStatus +' : '+ errorThrown);             
            }
        });                 
}
```